# После нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" кликнуть по ДИВ-у

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья.
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующее. У меня есть модальное окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" модальное окно закрывалось. Я так понимаю, мне для этого по событию **onclick** нужно нажать на DIV крестика. Подскажите как это правильно реализовать?

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clickSend()
    {
      document.getElementsById("cboxClose").click();
    }
    </script>
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="form[ok]" id="ok" onclick="clickSend()" class="rsform-submit-button">
```

Comment: покажите ваш html и js код

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить в вопрос HTML-код (и JS-код?), необходимый для этого модального окна.

Comment: Вот сама кнопка **<button type="button" id="cboxClose">close</button>**. А вот кнопка отправить **<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="form[ok]" id="ok" class="rsform-submit-button">**

Comment: у большинства модальных окон есть API, которое позволяет это сделать. Нужно знать, какие окна Вы используете

Comment: я использую **Modals NoNumber** для Joomla

Answer (score 2):

Неизвестно, как реализована работа этой формы, тем не менее, закрыть такое модальное окно можно выполнив `$.colorbox.close()` или `jQuery.colorbox.close()`.

Правильно будет- привязать это к успешной отправке запроса в форме и подтверждением для клиента.

Неправильно- можно, но не нужно.

Comment: Подскажите как его закрыть?
 `function closeModal()
{
 $.colorbox.close();
}` 
Вешаю на кнопку onclick="closeModal()". Не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: посмотрите в консоли разработчика. Может там есть какие-то ошибки. Для этого нажмите F12 в браузере и выберите вкладку Console.

Answer (score 2):

У `document` нет функции `getElementsById`(лишняя **s**), но есть `getElementById`. Опечатка? Если ее исправить, то код сработает (проверил на демо страничке colorbox).